# special characters not rendering well in zsh

Tags: terminal, fonts, zsh, oh-my-zsh

I'm running rxvt-unicode, with zsh + ohmyzsh.

I just installed firacode, verified font name with `fc-cache` and set `URxvt*font: xft:FiraCode` in ~/.Xresources, and ran `xrdb ~/.Xresources`.

Then I installed the ohmyzsh prompt powerlevel10k, and ran it's configurator. And everything looked good!

Except, when I opened a new terminal, it didn't look right (see image here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bkEWy.png). The '>' character in my new prompt was rendering well at first, with smooth edges. Now, after doing seemlingly nothing, new terminals show it looking pixelated.
What gives?
Does anyone understand why this might be the case?
Thanks for any and all help.

Answer (score 0):

This was fixed by turning on antialiasing by using:
`URxvt.font: xft:FiraCode NF:antialias=true`